# Spring Boot JMS ActiveMQ redeliver on failover

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have a consumer application that use Spring Boot JMS to listen message from a queue. This application is connected to an ActiveMQ cluster with failover to have HA. But I have the following problem, when I shutdown one of the broker and the application is processing one the message this message is not dequeue from the queue, and when the application connect to the other broker the message is redelivered. The problem is that the message has been processed the first time and I don't need to process it again.

I've been searching for Acknowledgement modes and I tried to use client mode to force acknowledge before message processing. But I didn't work. Any idea??

I've declared the following beans:

```
@Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl);
        connectionFactory.setUserName(brokerName);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(brokerPassword);
        connectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory());
        jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(false);
        jmsTemplate.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(REMOTE_T);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }


    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsListenerContainerFactory(
            @Qualifier("jmsConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setSessionTransacted(false);
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }
```

My listener's code is:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "Consumer.consumer1.VirtualTopic.TopicPrueba", containerFactory="jmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receiveMessageFromContacts(Message message) {
        try {
            message.acknowledge();
            TextMessage txtMessage = (TextMessage)message;
            mensajesConsumer1++;
            System.out.println("First Consumer:"+ txtMessage.getText()+ " received:"+mensajesConsumer1);    
        }catch(JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if I've understood correctly the client acknowledge mode.

Please help! :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you think that the message was processed? Is there no exception when you shutdown one broker?

Comment: When I shutdown the broker I got a JMSException I supposed that it is thrown when I tries to send acknowledge because the message is redelivered from the second broker. Moreover, the listener has a counter for incoming messages, and this counter increase its value even when the exception is thrown.

Comment: but in that case everything works as it should. It doens't acknowledge because of the broker shutdown. Or do I miss somehting?

Comment: If you review the listener code I introduced an invocation to message.acknowledge(); I supposed this would send the ack immediatly.

Comment: I assume that when the JMSException is throw it doens't aknowledge.

Comment: You should consider using Transaction with your JmsListener to have a transactional semantic

Comment: Sorry Simon, perhaps I didn't explain properly my situation. I debug my app and I'm sure that I receive the message but when I invoke acknowledge method the message is not dequeue. In acknowledge client mode I think It should be in this way.

Comment: JmsListener uses AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE so it should be acknowledged BUT if a JMSException is thrown then it will not be acknowledged.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense with my situation. I going to try without JmsListener.

Comment: Is possible to change acknowledge mode setting listener factroy object?? I tried in my code but It didn't work.

Comment: If you are using Transaction you don't need to set the acknowlege mode. Read the API Doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/annotation/JmsListener.html

Comment: I need to set acknowledge mode and no transaction because I don't want to process the message if I cann't be to send the acknoledege due to connection error.

Comment: And that's what transactions are for...